# Система для промо-кодов в телеграм боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Создаю бота в телеграм на aiogram, мне нужно реализовать систему промо-кодов. А конкретней, чтобы пользователь мог вводить определённый промо-код или же текст, только один раз. Если он введёт этот промо-код ещё раз, то будет выдаваться ошибка. Здесь не будет кода, подскажите пожалуйста, как можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, нет смысла рассказывать как создать промокод.
А для того чтобы проверить, использовал ли пользователь его, можно создать в бд таблицу из `"user_id", "promo_code", "check_promo_code" (Default = "0")`.

После предоставления бонуса выставить в строке `check_promo_code значение "1"`.
При второй попытке пользователя использовать промокод, будет проверяться `булевое значение` в таблице и если оно будет `равно "1"`, то отправлять сообщения, по типу:

> "Промокод можно использовать только один раз".

Это так как это вижу я и как делал бы сам, может кто-нибудь предложит что-то легче и лучше

Comment: Слушай, интересное предложение! Большое спасибо за такой совет!